# How to write css for specific div selection like before after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to write css for specific div
my div contain same name class

```
<div class="main">

   <div class="banner_image"> banner 1</div>
   <div class="banner_image ">banner 2</div>
   <div class="banner_image ">banner 3</div>
</div>
```

I need to write different css for whole div 
like after selection ....

how to write css on same class for different  div

Comment: not clear what you are asking for?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Have you tried anything to date? If so, please show it so we get some understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zxm3wgj2/2/

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="banner_image">banner 1</div>
    <div class="banner_image ">banner 2</div>
    <div class="banner_image ">banner 3</div>
</div>
```

try

```
   nth-child(2) // to select in between element

    first-child // to select first element

    last-child // to select last element
```

CSS

```
.banner_image:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color:white;
}
.banner_image:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.banner_image:last-child {
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
.banner_image{
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like `:nth-child()`. To select, for example, the second div of the same class:

**CSS**

```
.main div.banner_image:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Example on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zxm3wgj2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**You can assign both an `id` and `class` to a div**, so in the `class` css you write only stuff that EVERY div with that class has. And in the `id` css you write only stuff that you want to happen with that particular div.

```
<div class="main">
   <div id="banner1" class="banner_image"> banner 1</div>
   <div id="banner2" class="banner_image">banner 2</div>
   <div id="banner3" class="banner_image">banner 3</div>
</div>
```

You could also use multiple classes like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
   <div id="banner1" class="banner_image small">banner 1</div>
   <div id="banner2" class="banner_image big">banner 2</div>
   <div id="banner3" class="banner_image">banner 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.small {
    font-size:10px;
}
.big {
    font-size:20px;
}
```

I hope this clears things up for you. Happy coding!